# MongoDB query inside nested objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query my document which looks like this

```
"approvals" : {
    "REV" : "",
    "SS" : "",
    "ABC" : {
        "status" : "Sent for approval",
        "approved_at" : "",
        "approved_by" : "",
    },
    "XYZ" : {
        "status" : "Approved",
        "approved_by" : "xxx@abc.com",
        "approved_at" : ISODate("2020-01-06T09:48:22.777Z"),
    },....
}
```

The `Approval` object can have multiple sub documents like ABC,XYZ...etc, I need to query if this "approval" has any sub document whose `"status"` is not in `APPROVED` state

Comment: I am using MongoDb 2.6.10

Answer (score 1):

You need to run [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to scan your dynamic keys. Then you need [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) with [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to check if there's any `Approved` value:

```
db.collection.find(
    { 
        $expr: { 
            $anyElementTrue: { 
                $map: { 
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$approvals" },
                    in: { $ne: [ "$$this.v.status", "Approved" ] } 
                }
            } 
        }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TXVFEeQ5DQR)

Comment: Getting Error: error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "code" : 17287
}

Comment: @Odin you need to upgrade your MongoDB server at least to `3.4.4` since you need `$objectToArray` as the only way to dynamically read values when keys are unknown